# trace error in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, trace

actually i am trying to trace my mvc application but i am getting the error :

=======================

Trace Error

Description: Trace.axd is not enabled in the configuration file for this application. Note: Trace is never enabled when

Details: To enable trace.axd, please create a  tag within the configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "enabled" attribute set to "true".

```
 <configuration>
<system.web>
    <trace enabled="true"/>
</system.web>
```

=================

But , i already added the the trace tag in my web config file and its look like this :

```
   <system.web>

<trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false"/>
<compilation>
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

now can any one tell me what is the error and what should i do now

this is my whole web config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
                <add namespace="part_5_controllers" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
            <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <deployment retail="false" />
        <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false" />
        <compilation>
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant part of the error message:

> Note: Trace is never enabled when `<deployment retail=true />`

Comment: but i already tried to set <deployment retail=false/> still i am getting same error

Comment: The web.config you originally showed, had exactly that set!

Comment: then what is the solution ? @nineBerry

Comment: Well, have you tested with the current version of the web.config as in your question?

Comment: all set , but still i am not enable to trace

Comment: Well, do you still get the same error message? If not, show us the new one. If yes, show us the full current version of web.config that you use. Also check whether there are maybe other config files like "Web.Release.config".

Comment: sure let me add whole config file wait a minute

Comment: @SalmanAbdulKarim Please check your machine.config file at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config` or a similar place to see whether it contains `<deployment retail="true" />`